# trying to do a replace method in linked list but program replaces only the first element

Tags: java

My current code only replaces the first element of the linked list. I am trying to create a replace method with two parameters but failing. My current logic shows that I am trying to replace the element with my new input but I am assuming I am failing to traverse through the list as only the first one gets replaced.

```
public class ListOfNVersion03PartA
{   
    private int thisNumber;              // the number stored in this node
    private ListOfNVersion03PartA next;  // forms a linked list of objects
    private int []list;
    private final int nodeID;            // a unique ID for each object in the list

    private static int nodeCount = 0;    // the number of list objects that have been created

    /**
     * @param  num   the value to be stored in this object
     */
    public ListOfNVersion03PartA(int num)
    {
        thisNumber = num;
        next = null;

        ++nodeCount;
        nodeID = nodeCount;

    }



 public ListOfNVersion03PartA(int [] num)
{

    this(num[0]);  // in this context, "this" invokes the other constructor    
    list = new int[num.length];
    for (int i=1 ; i<num.length ; ++i)
        {
        insertLast(num[i]);
        }
}

 public int replaceAll(int replaceThis, int withThis)
        {
            int count = 0; 
            int x = 0;


        for ( int i=0 ; i < nodeCount; ++i) 
        {
            if ( thisNumber == replaceThis )
        {
            thisNumber = x;
            x = withThis;
            ++count;

        }
        }

        return count;
    }
```

Comment: You're never going to the **next** node...

Comment: Yes you are correct. I tried using  next.thisNumber = replace this but it still replaces the first. can you suggest what should I do in the loop so that I loop to the next node?

Comment: I would suggest you start with something simpler, like just iterating over the list and printing out each item. Then, move on to replacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've evaluated the current node (aka `this`), then you should perform the evaluation of the next node until there are no more nodes to evaluate. Here's an example using your current code:

```
public int replaceAll(int replaceThis, int withThis) {
    int result = 0;
    if (thisNumer == replaceThis) {
        thisNumber = withThis;
        result = 1;
    }
    if (next != null) {
        result += next.replaceAll(replaceThis, withThis);
    }
    return result;
}
```